# Is there a way to add Touch bar controls when using spotlight search?

Tags: macos, spotlight, touch-bar

I never found spotlight useful before, but now I'm thinking if I'd add calculator's controls like the ones in the picture, it'd make spotlight way more useful.
[image]

Comment: Spotlight's not a calculator - you can do calculations in Spotlight, but that's not it's primary function.  It's a global search.  If you want a really useful function of Spotlight, use it to open Apps.  Instead of having a dock full of icons, just hit `Cmd-Space` and start typing your apps name.  Press enter when it pops up.  I saves tons of time.

Answer (score 1):

I use Spotlight as a calculator *all the time*, without specifically pressing buttons, but simply typing my equation into Spotlight:

[image]

It's smart enough to realise what you're doing, and pressing {Enter} will load the Calculator app with your results, so you can continue / copy&paste.

Comment: I actually already do this but just figured adding a control strip of math-signs would help to make using it faster.
Just like In the calculator app, the signs being just above the numbers.